# When creating a portrait only, iPhone only application, are size classes in XCode necessary?

Tags: ios, size-classes

I'm writing an application that is only portrait and is only intended for use on phones. Is there any reason to go through the hassle of size classes since landscape and iPad won't be supported? Could not using size classes create a problem when submitting the app to Apple for review?

Comment: Yes, you can go with it. Apple wont' have issues if you use size classes or don't or even don't use auto-layout at all. They're for you own good. We've submitted an app in portrait mode only with just auto-layout and no size classes, and its live.

Comment: Sweet. With that being the case is there anyway to programmatically identify when an iPhone 6 Plus is being used so that some select graphics could be scaled accordingly? It's the 6+ that throws things off.

Comment: You need to use auto-layout to support all iPhones. It'll allow you to scale views accordingly on every screen size.

Comment: You can just detect the screen size to find out which phone you are actually on.

Answer (score 0):

You can go without size classes and it depends on user to use size classes or not, Apple won't reject your App.

I've also submitted my App without size classes and its is in App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Without sizeclass,you can't use present as popover segue.So you can't have an popover viewcontoller as iPad's.Many other usefull funcs prefixed with adapt is unavailable to you too.
If you just decided to forget them all,you can leave size class  alone.